# How can I make TypeScript avoid rewriting files if the content has not been changed between compilations?

Tags: typescript

There are a lot of utilities who rely on file timestamps and their cache gets cleared if they find out the file modified time has been changed.

Therefore, I want to skip rewriting files on TypeScript's emit phase, on basis of comparing files' contents. If the compiler is going to rewrite the same file with the same content, potentially it should be able to skip rewrite, why not?

Is there any parameter, CLI flag, bug on Github, pull request that addresses this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/issues/401

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, I'm not using Gulp and I have no such option at all right now. One more thing I didn't like completely is using fast compile. Yeah, it definitely can help but I'm interested more into how to squeeze maximum out of a regular TS compilation.

Comment: you can't really do more with tsc then setting the option, and the only option that's going to make it go faster is the isolateModules one. If you want something else you'd have to get something external. :)

Comment: @toskv , I think we can do more. Just in case if you're also interested: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16242

Comment: May be consider using `--watch`?

Comment: @unional , yes, this is also an option, however, in my use case it would mean that I'll need to write a custom grunt task ad hoc which is possible but effort-demanding. Originally I was asking about non-watch alternatives. Anyway, I've checked already TypeScript code base and your answer is the closest to the truth :)

Comment: I"m not using grunt (I use npm script directly) so I don't know how hard it is for you. You may check out this example to see if it helps: https://github.com/unional/color-map/blob/master/scripts/watch.js

Comment: @unional thanks! Your solution looks very sweet and neat. Maybe I'll write a similar Grunt task. Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: @unional, eventually I just wrote this task for my needs based on your solution and you're in credits. Again, many thanks! https://github.com/noomorph/grunt-ts-watch

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the best way is to use the `tsc --watch` feature.
You can create a script listening to the compile completion and then do whatever you want.

For example,

```
'use strict';

const cp = require('child_process');

cp.spawn('tsc', ['-w'], { shell: true })
  .stdout.on('data', data => {
    const text = data.toString()
    process.stdout.write(text)
    if (/.*Compilation complete/.test(text)) {
      cp.spawnSync('npm', ['run', 'lint'], {
        stdio: 'inherit',
        shell: true
      })
    }
  })
```

@noomorph has created a grunt plugin: https://github.com/noomorph/grunt-ts-watch